# Problema con Session Message

Tags: laravel-blade, session, alert

tengo un problema a la hora de actualizar o crear datos en un CRUD. Tengo implementando alertas mediante Session para notificar los cambios que se realizan en los datos pero a pesar de que es el segundo proyecto y esta basado en el primero, no funcionan, cuando en el otro sí, por eso me extraña ya que todo funciona de la misma manera y tiene el código igual, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

```html
    
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div class="header"><i class="ban icon"></i>
            <b>Se han producido los siguientes errores: </b>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>hola</li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    
        @if(Session::has('mensaje'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <div class="header"><i class="notched circle loading icon"></i> <b> Éxito </b>
        </div> 
       {{Session::get('mensaje')}}
    </div>  
    @endif
    
    
    
    

        <script>
    $('div.alert-success').delay(5000).slideUp(200);

    </script>
```

```js
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'nombre' => 'required|in:Hola,Adios',
            'caducidad' => 'required|integer|between:1,200',
            
      ]);

         if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('materiales/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
        $datos = $request->all();

        Material::create($datos);
        Session::flash('message', "El material se ha creado correctamente");
        return redirect('/materiales');
    }
```

Comment: Bueno, `message` como pones en el controlador, no es lo mismo que `mensaje` como pones en la vista

Comment: También te sugiero leer la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session), ya que si bien es válida la sintaxis usando la clase, en la doc de las últimas versiones ni siquiera se la menciona, y en cambio se usa el helper o el método del request, por lo que en el controlador podrías hacer `session()->flash('message', $message);` y  en la vista `@if(session()->has('message')) {{ session()->get('message') }} @endif`

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta! aunque cambiando lo que me has dicho y algún modelo que vi en Internet sigue sin funcionarme, cuando en el otro CRUD si funciona perfectamente

Comment: Ok. Pero entendiste que en el controlador estás poniendo `Session::flash('message', "...");` y en la vista `@if(Session::has('mensaje'))`, y que `message`  no es lo mismo que `mensaje`? Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar al final como quedó lo que has cambiado?